# ServicePointManager equivalent in java

Tags: java, android, vb.net, ssl, servicepointmanager

i am trying to convert a VB.net project into java for an android app.i am stuck at some point. 
**My VB.net code is**

```
Public Function SendWebRequest(ByVal url As String, ByVal postData As String, ByVal TimeOut As String, ByVal Code As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    Try


        postData = "Some String" + postData


        Dim webRequest As WebRequest = webRequest.Create(url)
        webRequest.Method = "POST"
        webRequest.Timeout = IntegerType.FromString(TimeOut)
        webRequest.Headers.Add(name1, value1)

         'problem is here
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3

        Dim bytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8().GetBytes(postData) 'Encoding.get_UTF8().GetBytes(postData)
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        webRequest.ContentLength = CLng(bytes.Length()) 'CLng(bytes.get_Length())
        Dim stream As Stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream()
        'stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.get_Length())
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length())
        stream.Close()
        Dim response As WebResponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
        stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
        Dim text As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
        streamReader.Close()
        stream.Close()
        response.Close()
        result = text
    Catch expr_1AA As Exception
        Dim ex As Exception = expr_1AA
        Console.WriteLine("Exception ReadSecConn:" + ex.Message())
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

this code sends a web request. i have successfully sent web request from my android app to web server using json. All part is clear except this two lines

```
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
```

Do any one know its equivalent in java, your help will be appreciated 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and learning a lot i conclude that there is no direct equivalent of 
     `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
      ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3`
But for setting **security protocol to SSL3**  we can use

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3");
```

hope this might help u